# Command substitution with pkg-config in Fish

Tags: shell, command-substitution, fish, pkg-config

Fish's [command substitution](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html#tut_command_substitutions) is supposed to be the equivalent of Bash's `$()` yet this simple example fails:

```
g++ -std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -g (pkg-config --cflags sdl2) \
    test.cpp (pkg-config --libs sdl2)
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lSDL2
```

If I run it in Bash, it works perfectly fine. Also typing `-lSDL2` instead of using `pkg-config` works as well.

To clarify, there's nothing wrong with `pkg-config`:

```
echo (pkg-config --libs sdl2)
-lSDL2
```

Why does this not work for Fish?

Answer (score 5):

This is a known issue in Fish, [#982](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/982). Apparently they want you to use `eval` or to parse the output to convert the spaces to newlines:

```
eval g++ -o code code.cc (pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs)
g++ -o code code.cc (pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs | perl -pe 's/\s+/\n/g')
```